# What is mouseResponse threshold and why should we set a specific threshold?

Tags: physics

I am beginner.I just started coding in codeacademy.In a certain level,the gave me a task which is relatate with  threshold.So,my question is what is mouseResponse threshold  and why should we set a specific threshold?

The actual question is give below:

1.
Three variables let you experiment with the animation physics: mouseResponseThreshold, friction, and rotationForce.
mouseResponseThreshold affects how close the mouse pointer needs to be to affect the dots that make up the letters. The larger the number, the more powerful the effect of the mouse interaction. Experiment with changing the mouseResponseThreshold to different numbers and running your code!

And the hint is "Try starting out by setting the threshold to 150."

Answer (score 0):

### What is `mouseResponse` threshold

This is distance from the mouse position to your target's position (in this case, the target is the "...dots that make up your letters").

### Why should I set it

You need to set it so that your code knows at what distance it needs to do a certain operation.